# How to apply Google reCAPTCHA (2.0) to my current HTML/PHP contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, recaptcha, contacts

I am trying to apply Google reCAPTCHA to my HTML/PHP contact form. The reCAPTCHA appears on the page and works, but I cannot get it to work with the form.

**Can somebody please tell me how to add the appropiate PHP code to integrate the recaptcha into my contact form?**

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    <input class="textbox" type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input class="textbox" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <input class="textbox" type="tel" name="telephone" placeholder="Telephone">
    <input class="textbox" type="text" name="business" placeholder="Organization">
    <textarea class="comments_box" name="visitor_message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LddnxAUAAAAAAi6jmmUcX8pPMfSELRgpNUAI2Ra"></div>
    <br>
    <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

```html
<?php

     if (isset($_POST['fullname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['telephone']) && isset($_POST['business']) && isset($_POST['visitor_message'])) {

        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $telephone= $_POST['telephone'];
        $business = $_POST['business'];
        $visitor_message = $_POST['visitor_message'];

        if (!empty($fullname) && !empty($email) && !empty($telephone) && !empty($business) && !empty($visitor_message)) {
            $to = 'acramirez38@gmail.com';
            $subject = 'Trucker Radio Talk Visitor Message';
            $body = "Full Name: " . $fullname ."\n". "E-Mail: " . $email ."\n". "Telephone: " . $telephone ."\n". "Business: " . $business ."\n".  "Comments: " . $visitor_message;
            $headers = 'From: ' .$email;
        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
            echo 'Thank you for contacting us! Your message has been successfully delivered.';
        } else {
            echo 'All fields are required! Please return to the previous page and revise.';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: where is the recaptcha checking code in your php form action. ie where your the private key.

Comment: Hello Geordy. I have not yet added it (have in the past but it keeps messing up). I need to know where exactly to add the recaptcha and private key code and how to.

Comment: Yes without previous full code I cannot find the problem. I implement Google recaptcha in one of my codeignitor project so really hope to help you